# Array index is not an integer error in OpenBUGS

Tags: bayesian, markov-chains, winbugs, r2winbugs, openbugs

I am trying to run a Markov model in OpenBUGS to estimate the transitional probabilities. But I am geeting an error "Array index is not an integer"
Here is my model code:

```
model{
p[1,1] ~ dnorm(0,1)
p[2,2] ~ dnorm(0,1)
p[3,3] ~ dnorm(0,1)
p[1,2] ~ dnorm(0,1)
p[2,1] ~ dnorm(0,1)
p[3,1] ~ dnorm(0,1)
p[1,3] <- 1-p[1,1]-p[1,2]
p[2,3] <- 1-p[2,1]-p[2,2]
p[3,2] <- 1-p[3,1]-p[3,3]

    for(i in 1:N){
      for(t in 2:T){
        y[i,t]~dcat(p[y[i,t-1],])
}
}
}
```

And here is my data with R code:

```
Data=structure(.Data=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6), .Dim=c(5,3))
N=nrow(Data)
T=ncol(Data)
y=as.matrix(Data)

#Load the data
sp.data = list(y=y, N=N, T=T)

Sp.sim0<- bugs (sp.data, inits=NULL, 
       parameters=c('p'),                       
                   model.file= "model2.txt",n.chains=2,  DIC=TRUE,n.iter=1000, codaPkg=FALSE,debug=TRUE)

print(Sp.sim0)
attach.bugs(Sp.sim0)
```

Can anyone please kindly help me to solve error?

Comment: the error message is saying is that the index here,

dcat(p[y[i,t-1],])

is not an integer. If i write p[XX] to index p, then 'XX' must be one or more integers. But the 'index' in my case are  observed data, y, and they are not integers.